# Store iterable into arraylist causing duplicates and missing values

Tags: java, hadoop, arraylist, iterable

I am trying to write a hadoop java code to find the relevance of several files to certain keywords. Current step I am able to output till =. In the reducer, I need to first count the number of files containing this word, and calculate certain indicator value iv. My output is to be `<key, value>=<word@filename, iv>`. I used `Iterable<Text>` for values, and as looping through this iterable twice is not allowed, I did one first loop through iterable values to count the number of files while storing the value into a ArrayList. I use the arraylist for the second loop to output. However, the output has a lot of duplicates, and many values are missing. Is there anything wrong with the code while I store the values into the ArrayList?

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  // sum up the number of files containing a particular word
  int file_count = 0;
  ArrayList<Text> value_storage = new ArrayList<Text>();                        

  for (Text val : values) {
    file_count++;
    context.write(key, val);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<value_storage.size(); i++) {
    context.write(key, value_storage.get(i));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are never adding anything to the `ArrayList`. Further, you are counting the elements into `file_count`, but never using the result value, which raises the question why you think you need to count them at all. So in the end, you are iterating over `values` exactly once, calling `context.write(key, val)` once per element and only god knows, where the duplicates or missing elements come from. Not from this code, obviously…